# How to replay incoming request in java?

Tags: java

I would like to send a response on incoming request by using ServerSocket, but i doesn't detect any response on remote server. Could you correct the code below or advise how i should to do that.

```
        try{
        server = new ServerSocket(4321);
        client = server.accept();
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
        String s = "SERVER: Started.";
        out.println(s);
        while ((s = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("RECV: "+s);
            ss = s.split("PUSH\\s");

        }
        FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File(pathToRReq), ss[0],"UTF-8");
        out.write("Some text");
        System.out.println(ss[0]);
        } catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

Comment: There is no remote server, the server is local (your program). How do you connect to it?

Comment: Sorry for confuse. I have a client and remote server. The client send request to remote server then  it should send specific response(json). I have created the remote server, but i don't how to send response on incoming request.